# rails paypal checkout page not showing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal

I have to integrate simple paypal into my app.
I am using following url as tutorial.

[paypal tutorial link](https://launchschool.com/blog/basic-paypal-checkout-processing-in-rails)

before directing to paypal page I print its url in logs, which is

---

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?amount=12&cmd=_xclick&invoice=19&item_name=testing&item_number=19&personal=omairr.azam-facilitator%40gmail.com&quantity=1&return=http%3A%2F%2Four_ngrok_url%23%3CUser%3A0x0000010a4e1528%3E&upload=1

---

But when I am redirected to paypal sandbox, the url that i see in my browser is

https://www.paypal.com/myaccount/home

and I cannot see checkout form that will take credentials from buyer and show details about transaction.

### NOTE: I am on localhost at this stage and have not deployed my app

Please help me in this, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is due to your return url, which may be improperly set. It seems to be appending a User instance to your ngrok url. Changing the url to something else takes me to: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_flow&SESSION=GcW-vpSKb2wALSTAyNuU29ltNqKyVjVwIuNy3mqgKDM_Df2abfo9PWP6KXm&dispatch=50a222a57771920b6a3d7b606239e4d529b525e0b7e69bf0224adecfb0124e9b61f737ba21b08198163eee001d8a5bd337af8e5197b2a388 where I was informed that there's a problem with your email

Comment: Yes I know that. But does not that have to do with the next step? or does paypal check the validity before hand? Although that ngrok url does not belong to my site but it is not some hacking data that will viral paypal. Should not paypal consider it a valid parameter value. After we checkout from its page and when paypal is redirecting then browser will automatically throw a non existence error.

Comment: hmm! Interesting thought! I think your return url looks like: `http://your_ngrok_url#<User 0x0000010a4e1528>`. I understand your thought though, however we're dealing with money here; so doing some of these validations later may not be an option. Also remember that after hitting that route, Paypal redirects you to final payment page, totally different from the url, so I guess the url itself with the other options are being stored somewhere at that point, so it only makes sense that the validation is done at that point.

Comment: yes. This seems to be the only reason why it is doing this. I will change it with proper url and will let you know. BTW thanks a lot for looking at my problem. If some other reason come in your mind, do share it.

Comment: Today I make a valid url and made the hit and voila it was successful. I am very glad that it is working. I really appreciate your help.